# Python: Dynamic instantiation

Tags: python, dynamic, instantiation

I need to make the usage of an object variable to cut way down on lines of code and complexity. Here's the code I'm about to use:

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
        'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        'secret': 'YOUR_SECRET',
        'enableRateLimit': True,
    })
```

I need to make the `binance` part dynamic since there's probably a few hundred different things that could be in this case. Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data structure is `ccxt`?

Comment: do you want to choose which method name you call?

Comment: In other programming languages, like PHP, this is a very common and easy thing to do:
`$method = 'mymethod'; $class->{$method}();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call each time a different method, you can use:

```
try:
    # get a method and choose it's name runtime
    yourMethod = getattr(ccxt, 'binance')
    # call it
    yourMethod({
        'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        'secret': 'YOUR_SECRET',
        'enableRateLimit': True,
    })
catch AttributeError:
    print "method with that name doesn't exist"
```